# Prove that $2^5+3^4$ cannot be expressed as $\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i 2^{z_i}$ for a given $n$, where $z_i$ is in descending order

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

This landed on my lap as a work proof, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around it.

You have $Z=\{z_0,z_1,...,z_n\}$ where $z_i$ are non-negative integers in descending order.

I need to show that $2^5+3^4$ $({}=113)$ cannot be expressed as $\sum_{i=0}^n 3^i2^{z_i}$, for some $Z$ and $n$. It is easy to see that the expression can never be $0\, (\!\!\bmod 3)$, but I can't find a proof for $2^5+3^4$.

Comment: $n$ can be at most $4$ (or the sum would be too large), so if all else fails, an exhaustive search for solutions ought to be feasible.

Comment: I performed the search and there are no solutions indeed, but I was looking for a formal proof

Comment: An exhaustive search is a perfectly formal way of proving the claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $z_i$ are nonnegative so $2^{z_i}\geq1$ for all $i$, and all terms of the sum are positive. It follows that $n\leq4$ as otherwise
$$\sum_{i=0}^n3^i\cdot2^{z_i}>3^5\cdot2^{z_5}\geq 3^5=243>113.$$
So then it remains to show that there is no solution to
$$113=\sum_{i=0}^n3^i\cdot2^{z_i},$$
with $n\leq4$ and the $z_i$ nonnegative. This is just a small finite search.

Comment: One also needs to exclude $n\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ by similar searches -- the sums for those cannot be written as special cases of of $n=4$.

Comment: @Troposphere You are right; I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I did the search, and indeed there are no possible solutions, but I was looking for a more formal proof